# How to enable 3D touch(static quick actions) only in debug mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, plist, info-plist

Our team is developing an app, and I'd like to add some home screen quick actions just for debug purposes. Also, I want it to be enabled immediately after a fresh install, which means dynamic quick actions would not be an option. However, I have no idea if we can enable static quick actions only in debug mode. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use run script for that.

Comment: It is probably not permitted to use a comment to say that this is a cool idea, but I'll do it anyway: this is a cool idea.

Comment: @matt Ok I expended it into an answer.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Cool, thanks! Unfortunately you're just using the run script to do the same thing I already suggested: you're changing which file is the current _Info.plist_. That can be done without a run script. I was hoping you'd use the run script to change the _contents_ of the _Info.plist_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major options for this:

### - The GENERAL option for any kind of file:

The cleanest way is to have separate files for each configuration. Then:

- You can set the path for each configuration in project build settings like this:

[image: Project build settings]

- Or you can use run script for this or any file you need to change during the build process:

  - Create two different `info.plist` files, one for the debug and another for production
  - Head to the project build settings and create new run script phase
  - Use the following script:

```
sourceFilePath="$PROJECT_DIR/$PROJECT_NAME/"
debugFileName="Debug-Info.plist"
releaseFileName="Release-Info.plist"

if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
cp $sourceFilePath/$debugFileName "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
else
cp $sourceFilePath/$releaseFileName "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi
```

Note that in this example:

- I use **Debug-Info.plist** for debug mode file.
- I use **Release-Info.plist** for release mode file.
- I copied all files in same directory as the original `info.plist` file.

But I made all variables and you can change them to whatever you want.

### - The More SPECIFIC option for any `plist` file:

Since `Info.plist` is a property list, you can use **PlistBuddy** to edit any value of of it directly. Here is the example script to add a shortcut item if it is in debug mode only:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :UIApplicationShortcutItems" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"

if [ "$CONFIGURATION" != "Debug" ]; then
exit
fi

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems array" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete :UIApplicationShortcutItems" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems array" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0 dict" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0:UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType string UIApplicationShortcutIconTypePlay" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0:UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle string Play" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0:UIApplicationShortcutItemSubtitle string Start playback" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0:UIApplicationShortcutItemType string PlayMusic" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0:UIApplicationShortcutItemUserInfo dict" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :UIApplicationShortcutItems:0:UIApplicationShortcutItemUserInfo:firstShortcutKey1 string firstShortcutKeyValue1" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Remember to run this script sometime **before** `Copy Bundle Resources`.

[image: Run scripts sequence]

I recommend you to always put script codes inside a separate file and call just call it in the build phase.

Comment: Very cool solutions. Never had a chance to use PlistBuddy yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the problem is that you are asking an entry in the *Info.plist* to be present for the debug configuration but not for the release configuration. The contents of the *Info.plist* don't come and go automatically depending on the configuration. But *what* file is used as the *Info.plist* is something that *can* change depending on the configuration, because it's just a build setting. So one way to solve this would be a special configuration and a special *Info.plist* to go with it.